# iPhone encrypted backup password forgotten

Tags: iphone, ios, backup, password, encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I forgot my local backup password to unlock the iPhone backup file](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29545/i-forgot-my-local-backup-password-to-unlock-the-iphone-backup-file)

I have forgotten the password used to encrypt my iPhone 4 iOS 6.0.1 backup. Is there any way to recover it?

Comment: The idea of encrypting something is to make it not-accessible without the proper key. If you could recover it without password, encrypting it would be useless.