# How to circumvent a forgotten encrypted iPhone local backup password?

Tags: itunes

I forgot my Encrypt Local Backup password for iPhone4S.

I tried to transfer contacts, photos, etc. to my new iPhone5 through iTunes with operation "restore from backup" but it always asks for a password that I can't remember.

How I can transfer contacts, photos, etc. to my new iPhone5, or do I have to enter all contacts manually?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enter the passcode to unlock your iphone backup file](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29545/enter-the-passcode-to-unlock-your-iphone-backup-file)

Comment: So you set an encryption password at one point, but now don't remember it? If that is the case, [according to Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4946), there is no recovery.

Comment: If you still have the old phone and haven't reset it, I imagine you can set a new backup encryption password and then make a new backup. Otherwise, I'm afraid you're screwed.

Answer (score 1):

I knew that you need the backup password to get your contacts, photos, videos, etc. I have the same situation before. You can find a tool to unlock the backup password, or go to Google Search: "iPhone Backup Unlocker"